# Rails 3 ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I need to list the most popular assets of a particular user, these assets being embeded in multiple blogs, each blog generating multiple view for that asset.
I would need the output to be ActiveRecord formatted, so that I can access the details of every pictures.

[image: UML diagram]

What would be the best practices and how would you do this with **Rails 3** and **scopes**?

Comment: Just curious, what program are you using for these UML diagrams?

Comment: That would be http://yuml.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adding a views_count counter cache to embed.rb. If you don't have the counter_cache and assuming you have this in asset.rb:

```
has_many :views, :through => :embeds
```

you can do something like this:

```
scope :by_popularity, select("assets.*, count(views.id) AS views_count").joins(:views).order('views_count')
```

If you add the counter cache it would now become:

```
scope :by_popularity, select("assets.*, sum(embeds.views_count) AS views_count").joins(:embeds).order('views_count')
```